# How to have a textarea which display only one row and expand automatically?

Tags: html, textarea

How to have a textarea which display only one row and expand automatically.
I found an answer regarding the way to expand area automatically and seems to works fine but it still display a textarea field with 2 rows. Even if I specify "1 row in the code.
any ideas ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("note").addEventListener('keypress', 
        function(){
                  autosize(document.getElementById("note"));
        });
        function autosize(textarea){
                    var lines = Math.floor(textarea.value.length/28);
                    if(lines < 1) {
                                textarea.rows = "1";
                    } else {
                                textarea.rows = lines.toString();
                    }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: please look at the attribute rows: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 1):

Use rows="1". as explained below.

```html
<textarea rows="1">hello one row</textarea>
```